# Keep getting an out of memory error when fetching many items on startup

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am fetching the logged in user's likes from the Parse Database. However when i do the query, I get an OutOfMemoryError:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 78089518 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 26MB until OOM
   at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:332)
   at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:149)
   at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:119)
   at com.parse.ParseRESTCommand.onResponse(ParseRESTCommand.java:176)
   at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:229)
   at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:225)
   at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796)
   at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
   at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:787)
   at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:599)
   at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:610)
   at bolts.Task$12.then(Task.java:702)
   at bolts.Task$12.then(Task.java:690)
   at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

The query I am doing looks like this:

```
    ParseQuery<Like> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Like.class);
    query.include("user");
    query.setLimit(1000);
    query.whereEqualTo("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
    query.addDescendingOrder("createdAt");
```

Something to note, if I limit this to 100 it is fine. Playing around with the limit it seems like it throws the error if the limit is more than 600. Another thing to note is that I do make a similar call that fetches 1000 items from Parse with no problems at all. It seems to be tied to this exact query.

Has anyone else ran into a similar problem?

Comment: I am not sure what your database looks like but it might be that your like class is very big and you are including every user (object) that matches current user in it (although I don't know why you would have multiple current users in your db)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you just fetch too much. Included "user" entity perhaps quite big and you fetch 1000 of them, which looks very wrong. You have to do it different way, fetch on demand or implement some kind of "scrolling" over the list of users. Alternatively you can fetch only some "user" properties that is enough for this particular case and the rest will be loaded later.

query.include("user.Id");
query.include("user.avatar");

Comment: looks like you were right, it was including user for each item

Answer (score 0):

You probably are loading all fields of the object, probably a BLOB field with an image?

You should specify the fields you need to use when querying then from DB.